# How to have a SpannableStringBuilder append a span that's inside a formatted string?

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, format-string, spannablestringbuilder

### Background

Suppose I use SpannableStringBuilder to append multiple stuff into it, and one of them is string that I format from the strings.xml file, which has a span inside:

```
SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder ();
stringBuilder.append(...)...

final SpannableString span = new SpannableString(...);
span.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xff990000), ...,...,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
stringBuilder.append(getString(R.string.string_to_format, span));

stringBuilder.append(...)...
textView.setText(stringBuilder);
```

### The problem

Sadly, formatting such a string removes the span itself, so in my case, there won't be any text with a background color.

This happens on the line of the "getString".

### What I've tried

If I just append the span alone (without "getString"), it works fine.

I also tried to investigate Html.fromHtml, but it doesn't seem to support a background color for text anyway.

### The question

Is it possible to format a string that has a span, yet still have the span within?

More specifically, the input is a string A from the strings.xml file, which only has a placeholder (no special HTML tags), and another string B that is supposed to replace the placeholder at runtime. The string B should have a highlight for a partial text of itself.

In my case, the highlighted text is a something to search for within string B.

Comment: After `Html.fromHtml()`, you can still change the span like normal SpannableString

Comment: I didn't use Html.fromHtml. Please explain what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found an answer to my special end case, but I'd still like to know if there are better ways.

Here's what I did:

```
String stringToSearchAt=...
String query=...
int queryIdx = stringToSearchAt.toLowerCase().indexOf(query);
stringToSearchAt= stringToSearchAt.substring(0,  queryIdx + query.length()) + "<bc/>" + stringToSearchAt.substring(queryIdx + query.length());
final String formattedStr=getString(..., stringToSearchAt);
stringBuilder.append(Html.fromHtml(formattedStr, null, new TagHandler() {
                                    int start;

                                    @Override
                                    public void handleTag(final boolean opening, final String tag, Editable output, final XMLReader xmlReader) {
                                        switch (tag) {
                                            case "bc":
                                                if (!opening)
                                                    start = output.length() - query.length();
                                                break;
                                            case "html":
                                                if (!opening)
                                                    output.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xff00bbaa), start, start + query.length(), 0);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }));
```

This is only good for my case, but in the case of general formatting, this won't suffice.

Answer (score 1):

format a spanned string may be impossible, because it still use String.format() to format a String finilly, it's a Java API, and Span is Android API.

But I think you can use html string instead. Look at this document [Styling with HTML markup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StylingWithHTML).

for example:

```
String str = "Hi <strong><font color=\"#00bbaa\">%s</font></strong>, Welcome to <em><font color=\"#FF4081\">%s</font></em>";
String text = String.format(str, "Lucy", "Android");
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(text);
// after Html.fromHtml(), you can still change the Span
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(spanned);
spannableString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xff990000), 0, 2, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spannableString);
```

the result

[image]

if you want to put the string in the string.xml, you may need to change '<' to '<', '%s' to '%1$s'.

```
<string name="from_offical">Hello &lt;strong>&lt;font color="#00bbaa">%1$s&lt;/font>&lt;/strong>, Welcome to &lt;em>&lt;font color="#00bbaa">%2$s&lt;/font>&lt;/em></string>
```

Comment: My use case is to search text within a given string, mark the found text, and add it all into a formatted string (from strings.xml file). before and after (as I've shown in the code above), I append other stuff (just strings for now) How can I do it?

Comment: It seems no conflict with my answer. After format, it is still a String, just a few more html tags, treat as a common String

Comment: Can you please demonstrate? example : the string within the strings.xml file  is "hello %s" . instead of the "%s" , there would be "world", and I search for "or" . The result should be "hello world", where only "or" would be highlighted

Comment: change to string to 'hello w<b>or</b>ld' in java code, I think this is easy to be done.

Comment: I think what you wrote is incorrect, but I think this is: change the string that will be inserted, to be one with HTML tags, and then format, and then use Html.fromHtml.

Comment: Sorry, my english is poor, but I think you have got the point.

Comment: Isn't Html.fromHtml less efficient than creating the spanned objects by myself?

Comment: What about this solution: https://github.com/george-steel/android-utils/blob/master/src/org/oshkimaadziig/george/androidutils/SpanFormatter.java ?

Comment: I don't think handle the format syntax with so few code is reliable, because the syntax is very complex.

Comment: What's "em" , and how come you don't close the "font" tag?

Comment: The text in "em" tag will be styled as italic. Sorry I forgot to close the "font" tag

Comment: How did you do the  text highlighting using HTML tags? Also, the input should be a string without any tags. Only placeholders. the text that will replace the placeholder will get a partial highlighting inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

*This is an old question, but I am posting a more general solution than the accepted answer.*

Reference is made to the following string resources:

```
<string name="string_1"><b>Bolded</b> <abc>Not bolded</abc></string>  
<string name="string_2"><font bgcolor="red">Background red</font> No background color.</string>  
<string name="string_3">The <b>capital</b> of %1 is %2\n%2 is the capital of %1.</string>
```

Android stores string resource tags separately from strings. Tags will always be consumed when read into an app.

```
var s1 = getString(R.string.string_1)  
var s2 = getText(R.string.string_1)
```

s1 placed in a *TextView* will show "Bolded Not bolded" while s2 in a *TextView* will show "**Bolded** Not bolded". The tag "<abc>" has no interpretation, so it is lost.

If the background color is known at compile time then we can do the following:

```
textView.text = getText(R.string.string_2)
```

will display:

[image]

Of some interest is that while the font tag is supported by the Android framework and the HTML translation class ([Html .java](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/Html.java)), the *Html.java* implementation does not support the `bgcolor` attribute, so the following

```
var s4 = "<font bgcolor=\"red\">Background red</font> No background color."  
textView.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(s4, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

will not display the background color.

If the formatting is indeterminate at compile time, then we must do a little more work. Replacing string arguments with spanned text using `getString(string_id, varargs)` fails as the OP notes. What is an alternative?

One way is to read a string in with placeholders intact.

`getString(R.string.string_3)` will produce the string "The capital of %1 is %2\n%2 is the capital of %1.". We could then search for "%1", "%2", etc. and make the replacements with spanned text. In this case, the placeholder identifiers could be any unique set of characters.

It may be better, however, to use `getText(R.string.string_3)` which will interpret any HTML codes supported by the framework.

The following code shows hot to make substitutions of spanned text into `string_3`. The spanned text that will be substituted simply has the first letter highlighted.

```
textView.text = SpanFormatter.getText(this, R.string.string_3, { Int -> getArg(Int) })

private fun getArg(argNum: Int) =
    when (argNum) {
        1 -> { // Get the country with a highlighted first character.
            SpannableString("France").apply {
                setSpan(
                    BackgroundColorSpan(0x55FF0000),
                    0,
                    1,
                    SpannedString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
            }
        }

        2 -> { // Get the capital city with a highlighted first character.
            SpannableString("Paris").apply {
                setSpan(
                    BackgroundColorSpan(0x550000FF),
                    0,
                    1,
                    SpannedString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
            }
        }

        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("$argNum is a bad argument number.")
    }
```

**SpanFormatter.kt**

```
object SpanFormatter {
    private const val END_OF_STRING = -1
    private const val SPAN_FLAGS = SpannableStringBuilder.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE

    fun getText(
        context: Context,
        @StringRes stringId: Int,
        argFactory: (Int) -> CharSequence,
        argStartChar: Char = '%'
    ) = getText(context.getText(stringId), argFactory, argStartChar)

    fun getText(
        cs: CharSequence,
        argFactory: (Int) -> CharSequence,
        argStartChar: Char = '%'
    ): CharSequence {
        // Mark all areas of substitution with an ArgNum span.
        val sb = SpannableStringBuilder(cs)
        var pos = sb.indexOf(argStartChar, 0)
        while (pos != END_OF_STRING) {
            var argEnd = pos + 1
            while (argEnd < sb.length && sb[argEnd].isDigit()) ++argEnd
            if (argEnd - pos > 1) {
                val argnum = sb.substring(pos + 1, argEnd).toInt()
                check(argnum > 0) {
                    "Incorrect argument number (%d) which must greater than zero.\nString: %s".format(
                        argnum
                    )
                }
                sb.setSpan(ArgMark(argnum), pos, argEnd, SPAN_FLAGS)
            }
            pos = sb.indexOf(argStartChar, argEnd)
        }
        // Replace all ArgMark spans with the appropriate substitution text.
        val argMarkSpans = sb.getSpans<ArgMark>(0, sb.length)
        argMarkSpans.forEach { argMarkSpan ->
            val start = sb.getSpanStart(argMarkSpan)
            val end = sb.getSpanEnd(argMarkSpan)
            sb.replace(start, end, argFactory(argMarkSpan.argNum))
            sb.removeSpan(argMarkSpan)
        }
        return sb
    }

    private data class ArgMark(val argNum: Int)
}
```

The foregoing displays:

[image]

And a simpler way without the use of the marking spans which aren't really needed:

**SpanFormatter.kt**

```
object SpanFormatter {
    private const val END_OF_STRING = -1

    fun getText(
        context: Context,
        @StringRes stringId: Int,
        argFactory: (Int) -> CharSequence,
        argStartChar: Char = '%'
    ) = getText(context.getText(stringId), argFactory, argStartChar)

    fun getText(
        cs: CharSequence,
        argFactory: (Int) -> CharSequence,
        argStartChar: Char = '%'
    ): CharSequence {
        val sb = SpannableStringBuilder(cs)
        var argStart = sb.indexOf(argStartChar, 0)
        while (argStart != END_OF_STRING) {
            var argEnd = argStart + 1
            while (argEnd < sb.length && sb[argEnd].isDigit()) ++argEnd
            if (argEnd - argStart > 1) {
                val argNum = sb.substring(argStart + 1, argEnd).toInt()
                argFactory(argNum).apply {
                    sb.replace(argStart, argEnd, this)
                    argEnd = argStart + length
                }
            }
            argStart = sb.indexOf(argStartChar, argEnd)
        }
        return sb
    }
}
```