# How to add customized spannable string with image to get this effect

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, spannablestringbuilder

I'm trying to get this effect.

[image]

I have a textview and at my required places I need to add the span with image and border around it.

With this [How to set a rectangular-dashed/dotted-line-outline around partial text in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938378/how-to-set-a-rectangular-dashed-dotted-line-outline-around-partial-text-in-textv/41940609), I able to draw the dashed border but it failed when the bordered text went to next line(it worked in single line).

I'm trying to get the exact effect as per the pic. Gone through the default supported spans from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/style/

but not able to get which one can how can I customize.

Any suggestions on this.

Comment: Any suggestion on this?

Comment: I suspect can do with custom Span like UnderLineSpan, Background span. But still looking for solution.